# How to select table base on it column

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I have a table like this

```
+-------------+---------------+-----------+
| employee_id | employee_name | upline_id |
+-------------+---------------+-----------+
| 1           | Andin         | 0         |
+-------------+---------------+-----------+
| 2           | Budi          | 1         |
+-------------+---------------+-----------+
| 3           | Citra         | 2         |
+-------------+---------------+-----------+
| 4           | Doni          | 2         |
+-------------+---------------+-----------+
| 5           | Erik          | 3         |
+-------------+---------------+-----------+
| 6           | Gana          | 4         |
+-------------+---------------+-----------+
```

then if I select where employee_id is 2, it's also showing the data like this

```
+-------------+---------------+-----------+
| employee_id | employee_name | upline_id |
+-------------+---------------+-----------+
| 2           | Budi          | 1         |
+-------------+---------------+-----------+
| 3           | Citra         | 2         |
+-------------+---------------+-----------+
| 4           | Doni          | 2         |
+-------------+---------------+-----------+
| 5           | Erik          | 3         |
+-------------+---------------+-----------+
| 6           | Gana          | 4         |
+-------------+---------------+-----------+
```

because in employee_id 2 the children who has upline_id 2, then children who has still have upline is looping until the last who don't have the upline_id is same like the employee_id.
Hope you understand, sorry my english very bad.

if I select the employee_id is 3
the data showing like this

```
+-------------+---------------+-----------+
| employee_id | employee_name | upline_id |
+-------------+---------------+-----------+
| 3           | Citra         | 2         |
+-------------+---------------+-----------+
| 5           | Erik          | 3         |
+-------------+---------------+-----------+
```

I don't really know what I am asking, hehe

postgre or mysql

Comment: I am confused :-/ hehe

Comment: Are you saying you already have this kind of query? Or you want help on writing one?

Comment: That's my question too @sagi

Answer (score 0):

The model you have adopted for storing your hierarchical data is known as an "*adjacency list*".

Sadly, MySQL does not support recursive functions, so using such a model one would have to make a self-join for each level of the hierarchy that one wishes to traverse—but it ought to be readily apparent that that isn't a very scalable solution.

PostgreSQL, on the other hand, does support recursive [CTEs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/queries-with.html) with which you can do:

```
WITH RECURSIVE tree AS (
  SELECT id, name, ARRAY[]::INTEGER[] AS ancestors
  FROM   employees
  WHERE  upline_id = 0

  UNION ALL

  SELECT employees.id, employees.name, tree.ancestors || employees.upline_id
  FROM   employees JOIN tree ON employees.upline_id = tree.id
) SELECT * FROM tree WHERE 2 = ANY(tree.ancestors)
```

However, this can prove very inefficient for large graphs.

The better advice is to remodel your data using either "*nested sets*" or a table of the "*transitive closure*" of your graph.  [@Bill Karwin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20860/bill-karwin)'s presentation, [Models for Hierarchical Data in SQL and PHP](https://youtu.be/wuH5OoPC3hA) is an excellent explanation/comparison of the various approaches.